# .rdp files are treated as 'text/plain'

Tags: 18.04, remmina

As it says in the title, .rdp somehow falls under 'text/plain' type. Thus, when I tried setting Remmina as default in the "Open With" tab, all other text files started opening in remmina.
Is there any way to disassociate .rdp from text/plain or associate Remmina with just the .rdp extension?